# Can Devise allow multiple emails for password recovery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, erb, forgot-password

I have the following situation:
A person model that includes **Userable**:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Userable
end
```

This **Userable** has many emails:

```
module Userable extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one :user, as: :userable
    has_many :emails, as: :emailable, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

**Email** has a model too:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :emailable, polymorphic: true

  validates :address, presence: true,
                      format: { with:
                        /\A[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]+\z/}
end
```

And finally, the **User** model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # devise properties
  devise :database_authenticatable, :rememberable, :trackable, :timeoutable, :recoverable
end
```

I'm trying to create the "Forgot your password" thing to recover a user password by sending an email to the user. But the problem is that 'email' is not a method at **User**. So, when I load the path "users/password/new" it gives me the error:

> undefined method `email' for #User:0x0...

So, is there a way that I can change my form to send an email to a Person email?

```
<h2>Forgot your password?</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Send me reset password instructions" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: Please do not try to validate an email address through a regular expression. This is going to fail. You are going to end up missing something and someone will be unable to use their email address (this happens to me quite frequently, and I just choose to not use your service). Using a regex doesn't even tell you if an address actually exists or not, let alone if the person entering the the data actually has access to that address. Please send the user a confirmation email asking them to follow a link to validate their email. This ensures it exists, and they have access to it.